# Setting up ssh to a url

Tags: ssh, apache2, dns

I have enabled ssh on one of my computer at home, so I can get to it from my main IP.

No I have a domain where I forward it to my ip. Lets say this website is called

`melikecandycoveredfrogs.com` mapped to `http://myip/`

I am able to run

`ssh myip` and sucessfully connect but when i try `ssh melikecandycoveredfrogs.com` it doesn't seem to work. I have the ports forwarded and everything.

How can I achieve this? does the `http://` cause the issue?

Please and thank you.

Comment: DNS updates can take a while to propogate propperly, make sure you restest after a few hours. Try `ping melikecandycoveredfrogs.com` and make sure that the first line says your ip address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using redirection or what? Mapping melikecandycoveredfrogs.com to 'http://myip/' does not make any sense.

For your domain to use your IP, you need to set an A record for specifying your IP.

In case you have a dynamic IP, I suggest you to use DynDNS, and use whatever method of updating the IP to the hostname, and then set your domain's CNAME record to the hostname of your DynDNS domain you use.

Comment: I am using redirection provided my URL provider. My IP almost never changes. I am able to access the website on port 80; so I would be able to ssh to it as well. right?

Comment: @garbagecollector No. Redirection will NOT work. Do you own the domain/website name? Set up an A record or ask your domain host to set it up. The A record should point to your IP

Comment: I was wondering does setting up A record also enable sites like this blah.example.com

Comment: The A record is actually the IP which is 'mapped' from your domain.
So if blah.example.com has an A record that means blah.example.com will map to the IP address stored in the A record.
Only with the A record, it can be known which host is actually trying to be queried with the domain. Use dig command to check your domain records eg. dig askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `ssh http://melikecandycoveredfrogs.com` or
 `ssh melikecandycoveredfrogs.com`? Try the latter if you haven't already.

Comment: I am trying the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the lines of command you wrote and that work/does not work, I would think that either:

- The new hostname (the one which does not work) is not available/visible on the net just yet (should be fixed by now). If this is a manually entered static IP address, make sure it gets updated as the IP address changes.
- The dns provider will not resolve to a direct IP address, but rather to a special IP address, redirecting web users to ads, before sending them to the real web site. This is the case for some of those free DNS providers. They make their money with ads.  In this case, I would recommend using somehting like dyndns, for example.

One thing you can do on the command is to use the nslookup command or the dig command. try it with both the old and the new hostname.

nslookup melikecandycoveredfrogs.com